# What does this Japanese message in the App Store when updating apps mean?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, japanese

I have been using the Japanese version of App Store for quite a while but lately I can't update my downloaded apps.

[image]

Every time I try to update my apps this message comes up and since I can't read Japanese I have no idea what App Store wants. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Totally lost why you are using the Japanese App Store if you don't understand Japanese.

Comment: Because there is games that I play in which aren't available in English

Answer (score 1):

It says the Apple ID you used is invalid.

Comment: What? How can I fix this? I have games that I have gone long with them how can I fix this? /: